# Simple Ajax call with result handler does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, google-distancematrix-api

I got this JS:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // we wait until DOM is ready
    jQuery('#veranstort').change(function(){ // fire when input is filled

        origin = "55767 Schwollen";
        destination = "13509 Berlin";

        jQuery.ajax({ // we build the AJAX request
                method:"POST", 
                url:"index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=6&action=ajax", 
                data: {origin, destination},
                success: function(results) {
                    console.log("results: " + results);

                }
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

which fires this php script:

```
$action = JRequest::getWord('action'); // we will need a parameter to run the script
if ($action == "ajax") { // if condition is met, run the script

    $origin = $_POST['origin']; // get the origin
    $destination = $_POST['destination']; // get the destination
    var_dump("destination: ".$destination); // this gives me NULL!!

    $distance = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$origin."&destinations=".$destination."&key=GMAPSKEY"); // build the URL according to the API

    $distance = json_decode($distance); // decode the response from JSON

    print_r($distance->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text);die(); // print the result so we can catch it in the AJAX call

}
```

This has worked for a while, but now it does not. I cant access the destination or origin value in php.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to send your data like this `data: {"origin": origin, "destination": destination},`. You try to send your data as an object without keys. Basically you send `{"55767 Schwollen","13509 Berlin"}`, which isn't a propper object nor an array. But in PHP you try to access the non existing keys like this `$_POST['origin'];`. Not sure how this was working before.

Comment: @Honkalonkalooooohhh — Err, no. You seem to be a bit behind on modern JavaScript. The syntax in the question is fine. https://jsbin.com/fivogovola/1/edit?js,console

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might give the results you are describing are if you have an `ajaxSetup` call somewhere that is breaking the way your data is sent. That isn't in the question though. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please post screenshot of Request header when Ajax request sent, If the data object is there in request header , There will be definitely issue in Joomla component assuming you are using RSform component.

Comment: The Form Data is submitted: https://imageshack.com/a/img921/4447/Mjjqr1.jpg
Yeah, could be a rsforms issue..

Answer (score 0):

The Error came from the missing `/` in the URL. It got redirected, and the POST data got lost with this process.

correct URL:

```
url:"/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=6&action=ajax"
```

Answer (score -1):

Script file it's fine . Please change the ajax file condition.

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action == "ajax") { // if condition is met, run the script


     //// Here process your code
}
```

Comment: They said the problem was in accessing `destination` and `origin`, not `action`.

Comment: That screenshot does not appear to be related to your answer at all.

Comment: In ajax file i have return the Request POST values. In console the post values are displayed.

Comment: Which just means you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, the Code after the if is executed fine. But i cannot Access the Values, and dont know why..

Comment: @VinothRaja — As mentioned already, the changes you recommend won't affect the problem. If they did, then the problem would be "The PHP never enters the IF statement" and not "The PHP **does** enter the IF statement but the POST values are `null`"